# How can we put the str_replace () function into a variable?

Tags: php, function, variables, str-replace

```
str_replace("~","af53261f02cbb39d10c6bb0e53d180da5fee7d3c4c784f632e35abcf33b08fdc","$encode");
```

How can we put the output of the str_replace() function into a variable?

Comment: Please refer to the `str_replace` documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php, it returns the results.

Comment: The _output_? It is a function that returns a string. `$x = str_replace(...)`

Comment: I tried this before and it gives an error

Comment: Please post the code you tried along with the error you are getting as an **edit** to your question

Comment: It turned out that the code I wrote was wrong, Morsi - I corrected it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

$variable = str_replace("~","af53261f02cbb39d10c6bb0e53d180da5fee7d3c4c784f632e35abcf33b08fdc", "$encode");

Was that your question?